# Podman image not updating like it has to

Tags: bash, unix, rhel, podman

I ran the following commands to change some lines in a file contained in a podman container:

```sh
# RUN THE IMAGE
podman run -it opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.2.0 /bin/bash

# READ CONTENT 

cat config\opensearch_dashboards.yml

# OLD CONTENT

while IFS='' read -r a; do
    echo "${a//localhost/0.0.0.0}"
done < opensearch_dashboards.yml > opensearch_dashboards.yml.t
mv opensearch_dashboards.yml{.t,}

# READ NEW CONTENT 

cat config\opensearch_dashboards.yml

# NEW CONTENT LOOKS FINE, CLOSE SESSION

exit

# RUN IMAGE, AGAIN

podman run -it opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.2.0 /bin/bash

# READ CONTENT AGAIN

cat config\opensearch_dashboards.yml

# OLD CONTENT SHOWS UP
```

What am I missing? I thought I could update the image, but it doesn't work. Everytime the replace works, it goes up in flames. I'm new to containers and I feel stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making changes in a **container** doesn't update the underlying **image**. A container has an ephemeral filesystem that only exists for the lifetime of the container -- when the container exits, the filesystem is gone.

Images are effectively read-only. If you want to make changes to the image, create a new one using an appropriate `Dockerfile`. You would probably start with something like:

```
FROM opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.2.0

...
```

Where you would replace `...` with appropriate `RUN` or `COPY` commands to modify the image to meet your needs.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I feel dumb right now! 